# FORTRAN - allocatable array in subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

I'm trying to use an allocatable array in a subroutine but the compiler complains that

```
Error: Dummy argument 'locs' with INTENT(IN) in variable definition context (ALLOCATE object) at (1)
```

The only thing I could find was that I am supposed to use an explicit interface, which I am doing. Here the relevant code for the subroutine:

```
    RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE together(locs, LL, RL)

    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE, INTENT(IN)            :: locs
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN)                                         :: LL, RL


    ALLOCATE(locs(LL,RL))


END SUBROUTINE together
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler's error message is one descriptive of the problem.  With `INTENT(IN)` you are saying that the object will not change, but you then go on to attempt to `ALLOCATE` it.

Yes, an explicit interface will be required for the calling, but that isn't the problem.

The Fortran 2008 standard says in section 5.3.10 that

> A nonpointer object with the INTENT (IN) attribute shall not appear in a variable denition context

Allocation is one such context: section 16.6.7, point (11).

Answer (score 2):

The `locs` dummy argument is allocatable, and has the INTENT(IN) attribute - the intent attribute here indicating that the calling procedure is providing information to the subroutine.

A consequence of the INTENT(IN) attribute is that you cannot change the allocation status (or value) of `locs`.  Your ALLOCATE statement is attempting to do just that.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense now! The reason I'm trying to do that is because I am trying to get this to work:
`IF (ANY(locs .eq. next(k:k+1))) THEN`
They don't have the same rank, I know that but I cannot think of a way around this without looping through the whole array

Comment: Try asking a separate question that details what you are trying to do.

Comment: Re the new question in the comment.  Set a logical flag false.  Set up a named loop containing an IF statement to check the condition.  If the condition is satisfied, set the flag true and use `exit` to exit the loop early.

Answer (score 0):

Try allocating your array in your main program, then when `locs` is pushed to your subroutine, use `INTENT(INOUT)` to tell the compiler you also want to change the contents of your array.